# MATLAB accumulation

Tags: matlab

I seem to be having a lot of difficulty accumulating and then outputting a variable in MATLAB.
Please see the code below. All I want to do is to add the decimal representation to the totalsum.  I've tried what feels like a million things. I think I am misunderstanding how to iterate through a MATLAB vector.  Seems simple enough.

```
%clear the command window
clc();
%clear all of the variable stored
clear all;
% close all plots and figures
close();

num = 1.32421875000000000000;
format long g;
%bin_num = dec2bin(num);
fprintf("binary representation of num:  %.45f \n", num);
num = num + (1/2^52);
fprintf("the next largest number is:  %.45f \n", num);
num = num - (1/2^52);
%bin = '0011111111110101001011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111'
sign = '0';
exponent = '0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1';
decexponent = bin2dec(exponent);
mantissa = [0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1];
for i = 1:1:length(mantissa)
     sumtotal = sumtotal + mantissa(i)*(1/(2^i)));
end
%num = (-1)^bin2dec(sign)*(2^(decexponent-1023))*(1 + sum);
fprintf("the next smallest number is:  %.45f \n", (sumtotal));
```

Answer (score 0):

There were some errors. I removed the errors and it worked.
Output is as follow

binary representation of num:  1.324218750000000000000000000000000000000000000

the next largest number is:  1.324218750000000222044604925031308084726333618

the next smallest number is:  0.324218749999999777955395074968691915273666382

Use the below code and please tell me do you want to do this ..

```
%clear the command window
clc();
%clear all of the variable stored
clear all;
% close all plots and figures
close();

num = 1.32421875000000000000;
format long g;
%bin_num = dec2bin(num);
fprintf("binary representation of num:  %.45f \n", num);
num = num + (1/2^52);
fprintf("the next largest number is:  %.45f \n", num);
num = num - (1/2^52);
%bin = '0011111111110101001011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111'
sign = '0';
exponent = '0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1';
decexponent = bin2dec(exponent);
sumtotal=0;
mantissa = [0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1];
for i = 1:1:length(mantissa)
     sumtotal = sumtotal + mantissa(i)*(1/(2^i));
end
%num = (-1)^bin2dec(sign)*(2^(decexponent-1023))*(1 + sum);
fprintf("the next smallest number is:  %.45f \n", (sumtotal));
```

Comment: Thanks!  Worked well.

Comment: If its fine for you and you liked it you can accept the answer by clicking tick mark and can also make it useful by pressing up arrow button. on the answer. Good luck